# Why does Clojure's range iterate only 32 times?

Tags: loops, for-loop, clojure, range

This Clojure code outputs 32 while I expect 100. Why is it so? What is a good way to make a loop with counter?

```
(def t 0)
(for [i (range 100)]
  (def t (+ 1 t))
  )
(println t)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` evaluates to a lazy sequence. Due to something called chunking, you are getting lucky here and `for` is being chunked into 32-element lazy partitions.

The code in your question is extremely non-idiomatic.

In your case you could just call `(println 100)`

If you want to loop over a sequence for some side-effects then you can use `doseq`

```
(doseq [i (range 100)]
  (println i))

;; or

(dotimes [i 100]
  (println i))
```

Comment: `doseq` is exactly what i needed, thanks! It is hard to switch from imperative programming languages to functional Clojure. Are there any sources with collections of good idiomatic codes?

Comment: @JayForeman head on over to 4clojure.com and get all the easy and medium ones done checking out the solutions of the top 10 or so other people. By then you will get it.

Answer (score 5):

a few notes:

- [for](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) in clojure is lazy, meaning it returns back a lazy seq. because lazy seqs in clojure are chunked, what you are seeing is the evaluation of the first chunk.
- You generally dont want to have side-effects when working with for or map (because of their lazyness). In order to avoid that you should use [doseq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) or at least [doall](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doall).
- You also dont want to def inside a function, that's not the proper way to do things in clojure. you should either use a more functional way, or (if appropriate) one of clojure's state constructs (such as [atoms](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/atom) or [agents](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/agent))

here is a more idiomatic way to get what you want:

```
; a more functional way
(def t (reduce + (take 100 (repeat 1)))) 
(println t) 

; a more "stateful" approach
(def t (atom 0))
(doseq [i (range 100)]
  (swap! t inc))

(println @t)
```

Comment: Two minor cents from my side: `(reduce + 0 ...)` == `(reduce + ...)` and `(swap! t + 1)` == `(swap! t inc)`. Doesn't improve the answer (at all) but I still wanted to mention it. :-)

Comment: @xsc I think you're being too humble.  I think those two points do improve the answer, by making it cleaner.